# Why isn't PowerShell ISE emitting UIA_Text_TextChangedEventId?

Tags: event-handling, powershell-2.0

I'm working with the UIAutomation framework in Windows 7 and trying to access PowerShell ISE 2.0.  Specifically, I'm trying to set an event handler for the UIA_Text_TextChangedEventId event.  In my toy application, I've added event handlers for ToolTipOpened and ToolTipClosed, just so I can make sure I'm doing it right.  And sure enough, I get a message back from the handler for the ToolTip events.  But from what I can tell, the UIA_Text_TextChangedEventId event is never emitted for any change in the PowerShell ISE application's text.

Why would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not really an answer, but I have found that PowerShell ISE 2.0 emits the UIA_AsyncContentLoadedEventId event when the text in the output pane changes.  So I can use that instead of listening for a non-existent TextChanged event.